# Inequal column bars (Google Chart)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, google-visualization

I have a google chart inside mat-grid-tile. One column has a value of `50` and the other has a value of `30`. These values come from service myService and they're correct. When I hover on those bars, that shows me correct values on tooltip. But the column heights don't seem like 50 and 30. That 30 one looks shorter than it should be. How can I make it correct?

[image]

Here what I tried

**TS File**

```
 ysData: any;
  options = {
    backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    hAxis: {
      baselineColor: 'none',
      ticks: []
    },
    vAxis: {
      baselineColor: 'none',
      ticks: []
    },
    colors: ['ffc000']
  }
constructor()
{
    this.ysData = [["Growth", this.myService.growth], ["Health", this.myService.health]];

}
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="12">
        <google-chart #chart 
         [type]="'ColumnChart'"
         [data]="ysData" 
         [options]="options" 
         [dynamicResize]="true"
         [width]="200" [height]="400">
        </google-chart>
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Just looking at what you've provided - I'd assume you also have to provide a "start" and "end" value. I.e the graph doesn't know if you want to start at 0 and end at 100. (your y axis begins at 0 and ends at 100)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the range of min and max value which in your case could be between 0 and 100 like below:

```
        axes: {
            y: {
                all: {
                    range: {
                        max: 100,
                        min: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

You can check the demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8dafm9u/2/)

Comment: this is for a _material_ chart, and will not work for a classic `ColumnChart`, which is being used. options are different...

Answer (score 0):

for the classic `ColumnChart`, set the range on the `vAxis` using option `viewWindow`

add to your chart options...

```
vAxis: {
  baselineColor: 'none',
  ticks: [],
  viewWindow: {  // <-- add view window
    min: 0
  }
},
```